# AngularJS scope model and scope method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Here is my Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ahopjILzzUp2WIBjePa9)

I need to understand how AngularJS handles scope variable and method part of given scope.

Below is my controller code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "";

  $scope.getNameLength = function(){
    return $scope.name.length;
  }
}]);
```

Here is my html body (just keeping my div for simplicity)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      Enter Your Name :<input type="text" ng-model="name">
      <br>
      {{ "Your entered name whoes length is = " + getNameLength() }}
    </div>
  </body>
```

As and when i enter something in the text box, the `getNameLength()` is called and the DOM is updated to reflect the `name`'s length.

As long as the method being referenced in a directive the method is called whenever there is a change in the name.

**Here is my doubt:**
Why angular calling all the method in the scope (which are being referenced in directive) whenever there is a change in view model? is it possible to disable this behavior? Are there any performance implication in this?

Comment: use one time binding `{{::`

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking

Comment: You need to read about how Angular's digest cycle. There are tons of information.

Comment: Maybe your question would make more sense if you showed us the actual problem you're trying to solve. It sounds like you are saying Angular is executing your function many times (more than you expect -- a common problem), but then you are saying Angular is executing other methods on the scope? That's the part that makes no sense, nor does the example Plunkr you give show that happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that Angular is calling your method too many times and you want to limit the execution, you can always use the ngModelOptions directive and pass in debounce. You can see the documentation **[on the AngularJS page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)**. For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}">
```

Will only update the model once the model has stopped updating for 500 milliseconds. You could also use something like `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"` to only update the model after the field has lost focus.

As far as performance is concerned, if it is something simple like calculating a string's length, you shouldn't have too much to worry about. If it is something more complex, you could run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Why angular calling all the method in the scope (which are being
>   referenced in directive) whenever there is a change in view model?

I do not see a custom directive in your example, but Angular directives will either inherit scope properties from their parent, use the parent scope, or have an isolate scope.

If you do not have an isolate scope, it will look for the property in the parent's scope unless you override it.

Because you have an Angular expression (the {{ and }} surrounds it), Angular makes a watcher for whatever is in the expression. When it detects a watched variable or object has changed, it will update all things dependant on it.

> is it possible to disable this behavior?

Yes, indeed, as mentioned by 'YOU' in the comment to your question, you can use a 'one time binding'.

Example:

```
{{normalBinding}} 
{{::oneTimeBinding}}
```

> Are there any performance implication in this?

Yes, the more bindings you have, the more watchers, the more the digest cycles will take, the longer it will take for your application to reflect changes. This is a concern for big applications.

More information about the scope, and watchers, can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).